# what's the best approach for implementing a bilingual website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got an approach for implementing a bilingual website. it divides a table into to tables that contain localized columns and non-localized columns. like this :

### Category

CategoryId

### Category_Local

ID
CategoryId
Culture
Title

I would like to know whether or not it's the best approach?
If it is, my question would be how to implement it. I mean how to handle CRUD methods for both two tables. I'm using asp.net 4.5 web form.

I would be appreciated for any ideas.
Thanks and regards.

Comment: There is no best approach at that - its about design and decisions on how you make it and depend from what is your needs.

Comment: Exactly => voting to close.

Comment: If it's not the best one, you should have something better, let me know please!!! I'm doing internationalization application with different roles and users for each language. thanks